# Cannot Resolve Symbol MainActivity (using Android Studio 2.0)

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity_main.xml has this code :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

The line tools:context gives me the error that it cannot resolve the symbol MainAcitvity.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: is MainActivity inside any package

Comment: Yes under  com.example.android.sunshine.app;

Comment: try to use it like this: `tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"`

Comment: then give the complete path of MainActiviy activity

Comment: Tried that as well it still gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

Give the complete path for

```
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

like

```
tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 1):

If this problem occurs everytime you create a new project and you don't even get autocomplete suggestions in XML layouts, try changing your `compile sdk version` or `gradle version` and let the gradle sync again. This solved the issue for me.

Go to **Project Structure Settings** by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` and

> To change SDK version

go inside **Modules** section change your SDK version

[image: Changing Compile SDK Version Android Studio]

> To change Gradle version

go inside **Project** section change your SDK version
[image: Changing Gradle Version Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should work. if not, clean build again. Make sure your MainActivity is there and visible. you can also try to give full name to your activity. you also check your manifest for the package and activity name.

if its really not working, there is something wrong. try to delete this attribute and run it to see you are able to run it.

we need this attribute for layout editor to guess a default theme, since themes are defined in the Manifest and are associated with activities, not layouts.